# Mongodb update datetime field

Tags: express, node-mongodb-native

I have written the following code to update a datetime field with today's datetime:

```js
User.update( {'email': email } , {'resetpwddateExpire' : new Date() })
```

The date part is updating correctly, but the time part is not. For example:

- if resetpwddateExpire starts as 2/14/2014 *8:08:52* AM
- after the update, resetpwddateExpire is now 2/7/2014 *9:08:52* AM
- but it should be 2/7/2014 *3:08:52* PM

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using Mongoose. It seems to me that when the document was created, the resetpwddateExpire field was set to sometime in future. And when you update it, it becomes today's date which is 7th Feb 2014.

Perhaps using $set operator would help.

```
    var oneWeek = 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    User.update( {'email': email } , {'$set': {'resetpwddateExpire' : Date.now() + oneWeek}}, function(...){});
```